# How to elegantly + robustly cache external script in knitr rmd document?

Tags: r, caching, knitr

Say, I have an external R script `external.R`:

```
df.rand <- data.frame(rnorm(n = 100), rnorm(n = 100))
```

Then there's a `main.Rmd`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<setup, include = FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
# global chunk options
opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE, autodep=TRUE, concordance=TRUE, progress=TRUE, cache.extra = tools::md5sum("external.r"))
@

<<source, include=FALSE>>=
source("external.R")
@


<<plot>>=
ggplot(data = df.rand, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
@

\end{document}
```

It's helpful to have this in an external script, because in reality, it's a bunch of import, data cleaning and simulation tasks that would pollute the `main.Rmd`.

Any chunks in `main.Rmd` depend on changes in the external script.
To account for this **dependency** I added the above `cache.extra = tools::md5sum("external.r")`.

That seems to work ok.

I'm looking for best practices.

- Is this **robust** (enough)?
- Is there a more **elegant** way to do this? (For example, it's unfortunate that *any* change in `external.R` will trigger a complete cache invalidation, rather than just invalidating only those objects that *actually* change).

There are **no side effects** (except for some `library()`calls, but I can move them to `main.Rmd`).

I'm always worried that I'm somehow *doing it wrong*.

Comment: What is the result of running `external.R`? Is only the object `df.rand` created or are there more objects or even side effects?

Comment: the result is a bunch of objects (dataframes), more than just `df.rand`.
As far as I can tell, the only side effects are some `library()` calls (which I *could*/*should* move to `main.Rmd`.

Incidentally, is there an R function that *tests* for side effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be better approaches than the do-it-yourself caching you currently use. To start with, you could split `external.R` into chunks:

```
# ---- CreateRandomDFs----
df.rand1 <- data.frame(rnorm(n = 100), rnorm(n = 100))
df.rand2 <- data.frame(rnorm(n = 100), rnorm(n = 100))

# ---- CreateOtherObjects----

# stuff
```

In `main.Rmd`, add (in a uncached chunk!) `read_chunk(path = 'external.R')`. Then execute the chunks:

```
<<CreateRandomDFs>>=
@
<<CreateOtherObjects>>=
@
```

If `autodep` doesn't work, add `dependson` to your chunks. A chunk that only uses `df.rand1` and `df.rand2` gets `dependson = "CreateRandomDFs"`; when other objects are also used, set `dependson = c("CreateRandomDFs", "CreateOtherObjects")`.

You may also invalidate a chunk's cache when a certain object changes: `cache.whatever = quote(df.rand1)`.

This way, you avoid invalidating the whole cache with *any* change in `external.R`. It is crucial how you split the code in that file into chunks: If you use too many chunks, you will have to list many dependencies; if you use too few chunks, cache gets invalidated more/too often.

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit more the last two paragraphs of your excellent answer?  It seems to describe a way to exclude from cache invalidation changes to a specified object (or objects) in external.R.

Comment: In the example, I split `external.R` into two chunks. Changes in the second chunk won't invalidate the first chunk's cache or the cache of chunks that depend on the first chunk. We could put `df.rand1` and `df.rand2` into separate chunks. What happens? If one changes, the other is unaffected. But by the same token this means every chunk that depends on `df.rand1` and `df.rand2` needs to list two chunks as dependency now. Therefore I would group objects into the same chunk when they are likely to be required as dependency by the same chunks.